# Play Store not compatible

Tags: android

i released a old version

using this configs:

```
  compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.application.id"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 3412
        versionName "3.3.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

and all dependencies using 23.4.0

after a i updated to

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.application.id"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 3415
        versionName "3.4.2"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
```

a special device is not compatible with the app anymore thru the Play Store

but the strange thing is, **i can run the .apk from internal memory, and its installed perfectly!**

i must allow this device to download from PlayStore, since most of my users use this special tablet, i dont know what is wrong cuz there is no error, no output, **the APP works in this device, but for play store, its incompatible**

im using the new Rollout system and testing thru beta/alpha not working for this app too

Comment: its a bit confusing that you have `versionCode 3415` debug version and `versionCode 342` which is lower... maybe try with 3420? you may have also some issue with proper signing

Comment: @snachmsm a fixed the typo, can you read again please? thx the warning

Comment: Please post permissions and features part mentioned in manifest

Comment: sorry, i forgot this @user12345

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the problem was a library using the `required` flag for camera at the manifest.

for someone having something similiar, look at the dependencies